# How do I iterate a list of json objects in an Azure Pipeline ForEach loop

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-functions, parameter-passing

I know I'm close to getting this working, but I'm missing something (hopefully something very simple). I have a function that needs to pass a list of an object into an Azure foreach loop. The object contains information that will be used to generate emails. All of the code is working, but I have not been able to iterate through it in the foreach (it just treats the list as 1 object and only sends the first email)

```
   results.Add(new EmailModel()
    {
        EmailMainRecipient = "craig@email.com",
        EmailCCRecipients = string.Empty,
        EmailTitle = "Test1",
        EmailMessage = "Test1"
    });
```

For the sake of discussion, I just do the above 3 times to create 3 records that are returned by the function as a json object (all of that is working). Where I think I'm missing the mark is in my "Items" of the foreach.  I am using:

```
@array(activity('Craig_TestingForEach').output.Response)
```

The foreach just sees that as 1 object and only handles the 1 email (even though I have passed in 3 of them as a list of EmailModel - and the input for the function inside the foreach does show all 3). What is the correct way to pass that list to the foreach so that it sees the output of "Craig_TestingForEach" as an array of the EmailModel object and handles each one separately?

Thank you for any pointers!

EDIT: If it helps... This is how I am returning the list from "Craig_TestingForEach"

```
return new ObjectResult(results);
```

There could be any number of results coming out of that function... I just said 3 earlier as an example.

This is what the EmailHandler function is receiving.

```
"[{\"emailMainRecipient\":\"craig@email.com\",\"emailCCRecipients\":\"\",\"emailTitle\":\"Test1\",\"emailMessage\":\"Test1\"},
{\"emailMainRecipient\":\"craig@email.com\",\"emailCCRecipients\":\"\",\"emailTitle\":\"Test2\",\"emailMessage\":\"Test2\"},
{\"emailMainRecipient\":\"craig@email.com\",\"emailCCRecipients\":\"\",\"emailTitle\":\"Test2\",\"emailMessage\":\"Test2\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after trying a few different things.  I just had to create an object to pass out of "Craig_TestingForEach" that contained the List itself...

```
public class EmailTempHolder
{ 
    public List<EmailModel> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Then once I added my output to the instance of the "EmailTempHolder", I could pass them into the items of the foreach using

```
@activity('Craig_TestingForEach').output.Emails
```

I hope this helps someone else that finds themselves in a similar situation.